# javascript not working onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onsubmit

I am learning JavaScript and this is the first JavaScript function I've created but it's not working and I can't figure out the problem in this code:

```
<form method="post" name="answerForm" onsubmit="checkAnswer(document.answerForm.guessAnswer.value);">
    <input type="text" name="guessAnswer" id="guessAnswer">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var rightAnswer = 12;

    function checkAnswer(guessAnswer) {
        if (guessAnswer == rightAnswer) {
            alert("You are right.");
        }
        else if (guessAnswer > rightAnswer) {
            alert("You went too far.");
        }
        else if (guessAnswer < rightAnswer) {
            alert("You're not even close to it.");
        }
        else () {
            alert("I don't know what you talking about.");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: When you say not working, how is it not working? Does it error, do the boolean checks not give what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code working well after removing the parenthesis at the last `else`

```
else {
            alert("I don't know what you talking about.");
        }
```

See demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/E3dgsd?p=info)

Answer (score 1):

In your function you have placed else with empty bracket which is wrong. For else no need of it. Please check below working snippet.

```js
var rightAnswer = 12;

function checkAnswer(guessAnswer) {
  if (guessAnswer == rightAnswer) {
    alert("You are right.");
  }
  else if (guessAnswer > rightAnswer) {
    alert("You went too far.");
  }
  else if (guessAnswer < rightAnswer) {
    alert("You're not even close to it.");
  }
  else {
    alert("I don't know what you talking about.");
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="answerForm" onsubmit="checkAnswer(document.answerForm.guessAnswer.value);">
    <input type="text" name="guessAnswer" id="guessAnswer">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Muhammad Aleee Have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you don't want to submit the form as there is no `action` attribute in form tag, you just want to inform the user about the answer.

You should be using `onclick` event rather then submit then and you don't need a form either.

just

```
`<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="checkAnswer(document.answerForm.guessAnswer.value);">`
```

will do the job